Location of git bash logs
I have an error with repository cloning - it freezes at the stage "Resolving deltas 100%".
I suspect network problems and for diagnostics I want to look at the GIT BASH logs (on Windows 10) - not the repository logs via "git log", but the logs of the git application itself.
(I want to see in detail what goes to the server from my PC and what comes back).
Internet searches constantly return results specifically for using "git log" (including when excluding -log from the search).
A search in Windows directories (C:\Program Files\Git, %appdata% and the like) did not produce results.
Does Git (on Windows 10) itself keep logs, and if so, in which folder?

Your question is unclear. git-bash doesn't have logs because it's just a terminal, it has nothing to log. Inside the terminal it runs bash.exe which do have "logs" called history; it's a history of commands. If you want a trace of git execution — git doesn't automatically log it, you have to enable the trace, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+execution+trace .

Your wording of my question was correct in my situation. Enabling tracing through the options from the linked answer is what I need.

I don't think there are logs. Even the verbose output doesn't really help with my testing. If you suspect a network issue, you can try a verbose output for the ssh communication:
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone <repo-url>


Thanks for the information - I was able to test my SSH using your command. It turned out that everything was fine (no errors).
Unfortunately, cloning hangs at the same stage, including via HTTPS.
To clarify, I suspect access problems specifically from my PC. Because from another device with the same git account cloning went without any problems.
And if the git doesn’t have logs, then I will need to look for other diagnostic tools.
